# jQuery target next of the same class in the whole DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this html:

```
<section class="slide current"></section>

<section>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</section>

<section class="slide"></section>
```

How do I target the next and previous `slide` class based on where my `current` class is, with jQuery/js?

Comment: So you when calling `next()` from the `.current.slide` you expect to get the first `section.slide` element - is that right?

Comment: Do a search on `.prev()` and `.next()`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney that only works on siblings, hence my previous comment about the OP seemingly wanting to get the elements within the `section` too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It was more a "do some research first" comment, I didn't even read it fully as no effort had been made

Comment: That I agree with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `slide` element can be nested on any level you need to loop each slide element when you click on some of them and then find `prev` and `next` based on current index in loop.

```js
$('.slide').click(function() {
  let all = $('.slide');
  all.removeClass('current next prev');

  let slides = Array.from(all);
  $(this).addClass('current');

  slides.forEach(function(e, i) {

    let el = $(e);

    if (el.hasClass('current')) {
      let prev, next;
      if (slides[i - 1]) prev = $(slides[i - 1]);
      if (slides[i + 1]) next = $(slides[i + 1]);

      if (prev) prev.addClass('prev');
      if (next) next.addClass('next');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.slide{cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;}
.current {color: green;}
.prev {color: blue}
.next {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slide current">1</section>
<section>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="slide">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="slide">5</section>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked just as wanted.